# Finding the limit of this function.

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I had a hard time finding the limit of the following function:
$$
 \lim_{x\to 3} \frac {xe^x-3e^x-xe^3+3e^3}{\ln^2(x^2+x-11)}
$$
using L'Hôpital's rule make the equation incredibly messy. Are there any tricks I am missing or is it the only way to solve it?

Comment: The denominator does not go to zero, so you do not need L'Hôpital

Comment: This is a real function, not a complex function :P

Comment: the denominator does approach 0 i had a typo

Comment: Are you sure you have the problem copied right? Because it looks lilke the denominator is non-zero when $x=3$

Comment: What was the denom supposed to be?

Comment: if u substitute in 3, you get ln(1) which equal zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
 \lim_{x\to 3} \frac {xe^x-3e^x-xe^3+3e^3}{\ln^2(x^2+x-11)}
=\lim_{x\to3}{(e^x-e^3)(x-3)\over\ln^2(x^2+x-11)}
=\lim_{x\to3}{(e^x-e^3)\over x-3}\left(x-3\over\ln(x^2+x-11) \right)^2
$$
so it suffices to evaluate

$$\lim_{x\to3}{(e^x-e^3)\over x-3}$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to3}{x-3\over\ln(x^2+x-11)}$$

(and then square the latter).

In general, the theorem

$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)g(x)=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\cdot\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$$

(when both limits on the right hand side exist) can often be used to tease apart complicated expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping that you already know about them, using Taylor series can help a lot for this kind of problems. The will be built from definition at $x=3$.

You could start using $$e^x=e^3+e^3 (x-3)+\frac{e^3 }{2} (x-3)^2+\frac{e^3}{6}  (x-3)^3+O\left((x-3)^4\right)$$ so working the numerator $$xe^x-3e^x-xe^3+3e^3=e^3 (x-3)^2+\frac{e^3}{2}  (x-3)^3+O\left((x-3)^4\right)$$

Similarly $$\log(x^2+x-11)=7 (x-3)-\frac{47}{2} (x-3)^2+\frac{322}{3} (x-3)^3+O\left((x-3)^4\right)$$ from which $$\log^2(x^2+x-11)=49 (x-3)^2-329 (x-3)^3+O\left((x-3)^4\right)$$ So, for the expression
$$\frac {xe^x-3e^x-xe^3+3e^3}{\ln^2(x^2+x-11)}=\frac{e^3 (x-3)^2+\frac{e^3}{2}  (x-3)^3+\cdots}{49 (x-3)^2-329 (x-3)^3+\cdots}=\frac{e^3 +\frac{e^3}{2}  (x-3)+\cdots}{49 -329 (x-3)+\cdots}$$ which clearly shows the limit.

But, we can do slightly more and perform the long division and arrive to $$\frac {xe^x-3e^x-xe^3+3e^3}{\ln^2(x^2+x-11)}=\frac{e^3}{49}+\frac{101e^3}{686}  (x-3)+\cdots$$ which reveals how is approached the limit.